# How to troubleshoot remote UWP AppService problems?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm playing around with remote UWP AppServices in C# and I run into a very early roadblock: Getting a `RemoteSystem` instance.

I followed the tutorial on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/communicate-with-a-remote-app-service with my own code and I tried out the RemoteSystems sample as part of https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples

Unfortunately, the result is always the same.

First I request access to remote systems:

```
RemoteSystemAccessStatus status = await RemoteSystem.RequestAccessAsync();
```

This is successful: `status` has the value `RemoteSystemAccessStatus.Allowed`.

Next, I create a `HostName` instance:

```
var deviceHost = new HostName("computer2");
```

Then I want to get a RemoteSystem instance:

```
RemoteSystem remoteSystem = await RemoteSystem.FindByHostNameAsync(deviceHost);
```

This throws an exception:

```
Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
```

### What I tried

- Searching the web doesn't bring up much at this time (remote UWP AppServices are too new)
- The event log doesn't have anything interesting in it
- The Windows firewall seems to be configured correctly (this seems to be done automatically by Visual Studio)

### What I'm looking for

One of my computer was upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10, the other from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. So there is a chance my computers are "misconfigured" in some way (I remember the unnecessary task scheduler entries for Windows Media Center...)

My question: What are recommended practices to troubleshoot these kinds of problems? Are there tools that can help me? Right now I'm now even sure where to start looking...

Comment: Did the exception has inner details? If you directly use the official sample for testing, can it successfully?

Comment: @Sunteen InnerException is null. As I wrote, I tried out the (official) RemoteSystems sample and had the same exception at the call of RemoteSystem.FindByHostNameAsync(...).

Comment: Same here - I have a Windows 10 laptop and mobile, with the same app I wrote that has a simple test harness using the proximal discovery & FindByHostNameAsync approaches - neither seem to work.

Comment: I have it working, by RemoteSystem.CreateWatcher(filterList).RemoteSystemAdded event.  The trick was to add an additional Capability declaration in the manifest: Private Networks (Client & Server).