# Project Rome - accessing Xbox console

Tags: c#, uwp, xbox-one

I am experimenting with [Project Rome](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/connected-apps-and-devices) and I am facing some issue with finding my Xbox console.

I can find my tablet, another laptop but I cannot find my Xbox console - it is a developer kit. I also tried to switch it to retail console but no difference.

```
private RemoteSystemWatcher remoteSystemWatcher;

remoteSystemWatcher = RemoteSystem.CreateWatcher();
remoteSystemWatcher.RemoteSystemAdded += OnDeviceAdded;
remoteSystemWatcher.Start();

private void OnDeviceAdded(RemoteSystemWatcher sender, RemoteSystemAddedEventArgs args)
{
}
```

I also tried to find Xbox console via HostName or IP, unfortunately it raises exception. `Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))`. It seems like the same issue with this method as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650752/how-to-troubleshoot-remote-uwp-appservice-problems).

```
await RemoteSystem.FindByHostNameAsync(new HostName("...."));
```

Comment: Do you use same account login in the XBOX one?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT Yes, I do. There is the same MS account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a problem with specific version (10.0.14393.2113) of OS which I had installed before.
Right now I installed following version and it works without any problems.

```
Xbox One Recovery Update [14393.2152.161208-1218] December 14, 2016
```

Even this works if I use `IP address` of my Xbox console (with `hostname` it does not work).

```
await RemoteSystem.FindByHostNameAsync(new HostName("...."));
```